# Can't get sympy to reduce a differentiate expression

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy

Consider the following code, which is best viewed in a Jupyter notebook, because of the mathematical output the variables `a,b,c` below  contain:

```
# cell1
import sympy as sp
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing() 
u, x = sp.symbols('u x')
f = sp.Function('f')

# cell2: building my function
a = f(x)**2
a

# cell3: doing some stuff to the function
b = a.diff(x).subs([(x,u**2)])
b

# cell4: now I have decided what f should be
c = b.replace(f, lambda x: x**2+x,)
c
```

but I can't get `c` to actually symbolically evaluate it, so that I get an expression that doesn't contain a derivative. I have tried everything, `simplify`, `cse` etc., nothing seems to work.

Of course I could specify a function at the beginning and then I wouldn't have had this problem. But the thing is I want to keep everything up to `b` and easily switch functions only at that stage as -for mathematical reasons- it is important for me to view how expression `b` looks like "abstractly", when I don't have already a concrete function in place, and investigate only afterwards see what happens, when I plug in different concrete functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.doit()` method to trigger the evaluation of derivatives:

```
In [25]: c                                                                                                                        
Out[25]: 
  ⎛ 4    2⎞ ⎛d ⎛ 2    ⎞⎞│    
2⋅⎝u  + u ⎠⋅⎜──⎝x  + x⎠⎟│   2
            ⎝dx        ⎠│x=u 

In [26]: c.doit()                                                                                                                 
Out[26]: 
  ⎛   2    ⎞ ⎛ 4    2⎞
2⋅⎝2⋅u  + 1⎠⋅⎝u  + u ⎠
```